# Need Help Calibrating Force Sensing Resistor (FSR)

Tags: resistors, sensor, calibration, instrumentation, fsr

I'm currently working on a project that involves using a Force Sensing Resistor (FSR). However, I've run into a bit of a roadblock when it comes to calibrating the FSR. I don't have access to a weight that can sit directly on the surface area of the FSR for calibration purposes, and I'm looking for suggestions on how to tackle this issue.

So far, I've tried the following method, but I'm not entirely sure if it's a valid approach. I placed a few weighing stones and a small plastic piece at the top the of the FSR to help distribute the weight across the FSR's contact area. While this method gave me some readings, I'm very concerned about its accuracy and repeatability because the same weights gave different values during the second run.

I would like to calibrate the FSR as accurately as possible, and I'm open to alternative ideas and methods for calibration.

Answer (score 1):

Use exactly 1000 ml of water (1 liter), that will be 1 kg.  Ideally you want to tare the empty container first (zero the reading).  When repeating the test place the container in the exact position each time.

If you need a smaller calibration value use water at fractions of a liter, (eg. 500 ml = 500 g).

If the contact area is very small try hanging the container from an "S" shaped hook, (place the sensor near the edge of a shelf or table, then allow the hook and calibration mass to hang below the sensor). The top of the hook will be placed directly onto the FSR surface.  If your sensor is made of a soft material use a small flat piece of metal about the size of the sensing area to protect the surface. (Before calibrating tare all the extra parts first - hook, metal piece, and the empty container).

If your FSR sensor is meant for a finger press you might go so far as to obtain a fake silicone finger. Then use that on the FSR with the hook embedded in it or just placed over the top of the finger. Just as above you would first tare the system with all the components (and finger). Nail salons actually use these fake fingers to practice nail art. And of course like everything else these days you can pickup a extra [fake finger from Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=practice%20finger&s=price-asc-rank&qid=1698653889&ref=sr_st_price-asc-rank&ds=v1%3ANRa29G%2F1SDDDs9VzLXdRVWKopFuu0KbMT9EMnX5nuiE).